# What exactly is unaccompanied baggage? How do I use it?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, terminology

This is my first time on a flight. So pardon me for the question. My luggage weighs more than the specified limit. I read elsewhere that in order to avoid excess baggage fee, one can send the luggage through '**unaccompanied baggage**'. But there wasn't any more information regarding the **unaccompanied baggage**. So how do I use the **unaccompanied baggage** facility? And what are the things I should know when I use the service?

Comment: Where did you read it? This sounds like they are suggesting you ship it as air freight.

Comment: This is probably specific to your airline.  What airline are you using?

Comment: First, I suggest reduce the weight of your luggage; the cost and management of either overweight luggage or tracking unaccompanied luggage will make your travel like hell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unaccompanied baggage is freight or cargo.

For the formalities you need to go to the excess baggage counter at the airport when you check in.

It is an alternative to having to pay excess baggage fees. The unaccompanied part means that your luggage doesn't travel on the same flight as you do; and the rates are considerably lower than the normal cargo rates.

You didn't mention the airline, but most airlines have a page describing the service and restrictions. Here are pages from [Air Newzealand](http://www.airnewzealand.com/unaccompanied-baggage), [Air India](http://www.airindia.in/unaccompanied-baggage.htm) and [KLM](http://www.klm.com/travel/kw_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/excess/index.htm) to give you an idea of what this service entails.

Comment: *the rates are considerably lower than the normal cargo rates*, not necessarily, if I ship 200 kg of personal goods by sea freight through a moving company, that will cost me less than if I show up at the airport and book unaccompanied baggage on the spot.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clear that I mean _air cargo_ `:)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it was perfectly clear to me, at least.

Comment: I would like to add that at the destination, there's a good chance you may have to pick up your stuff from some cargo facility which is not necessarily easy to get to (especially via public transport), and that customs handling of such cargo is often a PITA. Be prepared to waste quite some time managing all of this.